# Eclipse autocomplete in xml editor

Tags: eclipse, springsource

How to configure eclipse to autocomplete at least class full path on Ctrl+Space in xml editor?
I am using springsource tool suite (its same eclipse), there IDE understands when it is beans config file and auto complete works. But elsewhere in just xml file, this doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Rinzo XML editor if you like which does what you are asking for:

http://editorxml.sourceforge.net/

Best Regards!

Comment: You should accept this answer by clicking on the check mark below the reputation. Also you should go through any other answers that have been correctly answered and accept them. Not only does it give the person who answered rep, you get 2 yourself I believe

Answer (score 1):

perfect! But I wonder why eclipse Mars do not have "Other Java Proposals" in Java > Editor > Content Assit -> Advanced.

[image]